# Why didn't work SASS Build in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: css, sublimetext2, sass

When i try build scss file, nothing happens.

Error message in Sublime Console:

```
Running sass --update C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\Open Server\html\print-service.loc\www\css\sourse.scss:C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\Open Server\html\print-service.loc\www\css/sourse.css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File ".\exec.py", line 154, in run
  File ".\exec.py", line 45, in __init__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 919: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why may this happen?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing Unix-style and Windows-style path names. Is this intentional? How do you build the SASS file?

Comment: I installed plugin for sublime, SASS Build.

Comment: Ruby sass build file correctly, so problem should by with sublime text.